# How to remove/change JavaScript code from sp.ribbon.js?

Tags: 2010, web-part, ribbon

I use [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407578.aspx) link for created a ribbon on my web part.

I run the solution and it is OK. but when i change the JavaScript code it is run the old code.

I remove the JavaScript code in solution and add again. But again, the old code runs.

Comment: This question title is a bit misleading. It is highly recommended NEVER to change the contents of sp.ribbon.js, as this will put your environment into an unsupportable state, and chances are the next CU update will overwrite the changes anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your browser temporary files and try. Even if this doesn't solve the issue then issreset your server.